# Hive unable to manually set number of reducers

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

I have the following hive query:

```
select count(distinct id) as total from mytable;
```

which automatically spawns:
1408 Mappers
1 Reducer

I need to manually set the number of reducers and I have tried the following:

```
set mapred.reduce.tasks=50 
set hive.exec.reducers.max=50
```

but none of these settings seem to be honored. The query takes forever to run. Is there a way to manually set the reducers or maybe rewrite the query so it can result in more reducers? Thanks!

Comment: How many nodes are you using?

Comment: It doesn't matter Tudor, even if he had only reduce slot, he could still have more reducers.

Comment: I doubt this is true since you have 1400 mappers, but are you running in local mode? If so, that'll keep your reducer at 1, I believe.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

writing query in hive like this:

```
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) ....
```

will always result in using only one reducer.
You should:

1. use this command to set desired number of reducers:

   set mapred.reduce.tasks=50
2. rewrite query as following:

> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT id FROM ... ) t;

This will result in 2 map+reduce jobs instead of one, but performance gain will be substantial.

Comment: cool. how comes the hive compiler doesn't do this optimization (turning into 2 MR jobs) by itself automatically?

Comment: There are situations where turning this into 2 MR jobs isn't an optimization. For instance, if id is already close to unique and the table is stored in a columnar file format (like RCFILE), than 1 MR job would certainly be better. Since situations like that aren't outlandish, I imagine that's why no one has built this optimization into Hive.

Answer (score 11):

Number of reducers depends also on size of the input file

By default it is 1GB (1000000000 bytes). You could change that by setting the property hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer:

1. either by changing hive-site.xml

   ```
   <property>
      <name>hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer</name>
      <value>1000000</value>
   </property>
   ```
2. or using set

   `$ hive -e "set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=1000000"`

Answer (score 1):

You could set the number of reducers spawned per node in the `conf/mapred-site.xml` config file. See here: http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.0/cluster_setup.html.

In particular, you need to set this property:

```
mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum
```

Comment: that is applicable for all jobs. If you want to set for a specific query, i think it is better use `set mapred.reduce.tasks`

Answer (score 1):

**Mapper** is totaly depend on number of file i.e size of file we can call it as input splits. Split is noting but the logical split of data.
Ex: my file size is 150MB and my HDFS default block is 128MB. It will create two split means two blocks. Two Mapper will get assigned for this job.

**Imp Note:** Suppose I have specified the split size is 50MB then It will start 3 Mapper because of it totally depend on number of split.

**Imp Note:** if you expect **10TB** of input data and have a blocksize of **128MB**, you’ll end up with **82,000 maps**, unless Configuration.set(MRJobConfig.NUM_MAPS, int) (which only provides a hint to the framework) is used to set it even higher.

**Note:** If we haven't specifyed the split size it will take default hdfs block size as split size.

**Reducer** has 3 primary phases: **shuffle, sort and reduce**.

**Command :**

1] Set Map Task : **-D mapred.map.tasks=4**
2] Set Reduce Task : **-D mapred.reduce.tasks=2**