# Amazon EMR not utilizing all the nodes

Tags: hadoop, hive, emr

I am using 4 core nodes..

I am using hive to run queries on a table.

Various queries seem to be under utilizing the capacity.

My table consists of 8 integer fields and about 1000 rows.

queries of the form

select avg(col1-col2) from tbl; 
select count(*) from tbl;
and every other query I tried
are producing

number of reducers=1,number of mappers=1

i have tried using  set mapred.reduce.tasks=4;

but it doesnt work.

The weirdest thing is that when I use mapred.job.tracker=local which means one map and one reduce on the local node itself the task finished twice as fast.

All the reduce/map slots except one are open all the time.

Why isnt adding capacity even slightly improving exec time?
Is my data sample so small that increasing capacity doesn't matter and localizing the mapping and reduction actually improves the time?

Comment: I am not logging into S3.How do i check whether the tasktracjer is working properly or not?

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting a single mapper is because your table is so small. I'm assuming your 1000 row table is one file which is much smaller than then your HDFS block size. Try a million row table or larger and you will start seeing it utilize multiple mappers. [The answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9678180/change-file-split-size-in-hadoop/10083814#10083814) has some more information on how the number of mappers is chosen.

The reason you are getting a single reducer is a combination of two things. First, you are working with a tiny amount of data (for Hive) so you end up with one reducer. Second, some queries (like `COUNT(*) FROM some_table`) must have one reducer ([see the question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762064/hive-unable-to-manually-set-number-of-reducers?rq=1))

You nailed it on why running the job locally is faster. 1000 row tables are great for testing the logic of your queries, but not for determining things like runtime. Running Hive on a cluster instead of locally will probably only start being better once you have data on the order of GBs. Hive is definitely not the "right tool for the job" until you get into queries that touch at least 10's of GBs, though 100's of GBs or TBs (or more) is easier to justify.