# SQL/Hive count distinct column

Tags: sql, hive

How do I do this in SQL/Hive?

```
    columnA       columnB    columnC
     100.10      50.60       30
     100.10      50.60       30
     100.10      50.60       20
     100.10      70.80       40
```

Output should be:

```
  columnA   columnB    No_of_distinct_colC
  100.10    50.60       2
  100.10    70.80       1
```

Query that I think is correct:

```
SELECT columnA,columnB,COUNT(distinct column C)
from table_name
group by columnA,columnB
```

Comment: Yes, your SQL looks fine.

Comment: Query looks fine, but using `COUNT(DISTINCT(X))` may not give the most efficient execution result. See also this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762064/hive-unable-to-manually-set-number-of-reducers/8770568#8770568

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes, it is almost correct. But you have one simple mistake. Your column name is wrong inside COUNT.

```
SELECT columnA,columnB,COUNT(DISTINCT columnC) No_of_distinct_colC
from table_name
group by columnA,columnB
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing the distinct for columnC.

Comment: Do you really need distinct? I don't think so. It should work as expected.

Comment: "count(expr) - Returns the number of rows for which the supplied expression is non-NULL; count(DISTINCT expr[, expr]) - Returns the number of rows for which the supplied expression(s) are unique and non-NULL." https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF

Comment: Without `DISTINCT`, the query will return a row "100.10, 50.60, 3" (there are three rows with 100.10, 50.60 for A and B respectively) while the requirement is to return "100.10, 50.60, 2" (because the first two rows have the same value for C).

Comment: @AgentSQl: Isn't that what I did? COUNT(DISTINCT columnC)?

Comment: @user2441441 I told you its a small mistake. You did COUNT(distinct column C). Just a column name don't match with the column in your example. It should be columnC. I am sure you already figure it yourself. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

the following code should work if you are using PySpark:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
spark.sql('select * from table_name')\
         .groupby(columnA, columnB)\
         .agg(F.countDistinct('columnC') ).show()
```

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
    SELECT columnA, columnB, COUNT(DISTINCT column C) AS dis_col
    FROM table_name
    GROUP BY columnA, columnB
) A;
```

Comment: Inner query would do right, why do you need the outer `SELECT *` query?

Comment: To expand on the previous comment there is no reason you would need a select * from an outer query on an inner query.  That's like saying get only red cups, then get all the cups that you just got.