# How to set the resources for different hive stages from the EXPLAIN?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

Is there any way to provide resources basing on the stages from the EXPLAIN query.

Comment: What do you mean by *"provide resources"* -- specify how many containers to use for each step? how much RAM / cores per container? both?

Comment: @Samson yes, I am referring to the containers and the associated rRAM/cores.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK the only things you can set are:

- number of R / exact count `set mapred.reduce.tasks=**` *(as long as it [makes sense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762064/hive-unable-to-manually-set-number-of-reducers))*
- number of R / max count `set hive.exec.reducers.max=**` + hint for computing the actual number `set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=*****`
- resources per M container (when using MR) / `set mapreduce.map.memory.mb=**` + `set mapreduce.map.java.opts=-XMX**`  <~80% of total for heap>
- resources per R container (when using MR) / `set mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=**` + `set mapreduce.reduce.java.opts=-XMX**`  <~80% of total for heap>
- resources per container (when using TEZ) / `set hive.tez.container.size=**` + `set hive.tez.java.opts=-XMX**` <~80% of total for heap>

Note that if your query shows 3 Map steps and 2 Reduce steps, the settings will apply to *all* steps...

Reference : [Hive documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties) and [that post for instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005643/container-is-running-beyond-memory-limits)